# What is the combinatorial interpretation behind the recursive relation: $L(n,k+1)=\frac{n-k}{k\left(k+1\right)}L(n,k)$

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorial-proofs

What is the combinatorial interpretation behind the following recursive relation:
$$L(n,k+1)=\frac{n-k}{k\left(k+1\right)}L(n,k)$$

Where $L(n,k)$ denotes Lah numbers.

---

I tried the same method ,setting $n+1 \mapsto n $ and $k \mapsto k+1$ gives:

$$L(n,k+1)=(n-1,k+1)L(n-1,k+1)+L(n-1,k)$$

It seems that after some algebra the desired relation can be derived,but does there exist a direct combinatorial proof?

Answer (score 1):

It’s easier to interpret the equivalent equation

$$k(k+1)L(n,k+1)=(n-k)L(n,k)\,.\tag{1}$$

The lefthand side of $(1)$ is the number of ways to partition $[n]=\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ into $k+1$ ordered lists and label one of the lists $a$ and another $b$. We can then append the list $b$ to the list $a$ to form a single list $c$ and mark the element of $c$ that was the first element of $b$. This produces a partition of $[n]$ into $k$ ordered lists, one of which contains a marked element that is not the first element of that list.

The lefthand side of $(1)$ is the number of ways to partition $[n]$ into $k$ ordered lists and mark one of the $n-k$ elements that are not the first element of any list. If we have one of these partitions, we can take the list $c$ that contains the marked element and split it into sublists that we mark $a$ and $b$: $a$ contains the elements that precede the marked element of $c$, and $b$ contains the marked element and those that follow it in $c$. Clearly this operation is the inverse of the operation described in the first paragraph, so I’ve described a bijection that establishes $(1)$.

Comment: @45465: No, you have to choose one of them to be $a$, the **first** part of $c$, and then another to be $b$, the **second** part of $c$. In other words, you have to choose an **ordered** pair of distinct lists, and there are $(k+1)k$ of those.

Comment: @45465: You’re forgetting that we mark the element of $c$ that was the first element of $b$, so that in your first case $c=\langle 2,\color{red}{1},3\rangle$, while in the second case it’s $\langle 2,1,\color{red}3\rangle$. Otherwise we couldn’t reverse the transformation.

Comment: @45465: I just told you: we do it so that we know where to split $c$ to recover $a$ and $b$. Otherwise we wouldn’t have a bijection.

Comment: For your example the $12$ marked lists from $[3]$ are $\langle 1,\color{red}2,3\rangle$, $\langle 2,3,\color{red}1\rangle$, $\langle 1,\color{red}3,2\rangle$, $\langle 3,2,\color{red}1\rangle$, $\langle 2,\color{red}1,3\rangle$, $\langle 1,3,\color{red}2\rangle$, $\langle 2,\color{red}3,1\rangle$, $\langle 3,1,\color{red}2\rangle$, $\langle 3,\color{red}1,2\rangle$, $\langle 1,2,\color{red}3\rangle$, $\langle 3,\color{red}2,1\rangle$, and $\langle 2,1,\color{red}3\rangle$, corresponding to the $12$ ways to combine the $6$ pairs of lists.

Comment: @45465: $a=\langle 2,3\rangle$, $b=\langle 1\rangle$.

Comment: @45465: Let $\mathscr{P}_1$ be the set of partitions of $[n]$ into $k+1$ ordered lists, one of which is labelled $a$ and another of which is labelled $b$, and let $\mathscr{P}_2$ be the set of partitions of $[n]$ into $k$ ordered lists in which one list contains a marked element that is not the first element of that list. In the first paragraph I described a mapping from $\mathscr{P}_1$ to $\mathscr{P}_2$; call it $f$. In the second paragraph I described a mapping from $\mathscr{P}_2$ to $\mathscr{P}_1$ that is easily seen to be $f^{-1}$, thereby showing that $f$ and $f^{-1}$ are bijections.

Comment: @45465: An element of $\mathscr{P}_1$ is a partition of $[n]$ into $k+1$ lists, one of which is labelled $a$ and another $b$. Call it $P$. The first paragraph of my answer tells you exactly which member of $\mathscr{P}_2$ $f(P)$ is. The second tells you exactly what $f^{-1}$ does to a member of $\mathscr{P}_2$.